# NthPrime- what's wrong with this while/for loop or set of if-statements?

Tags: java, eclipse

Having trouble understanding what's wrong in the code.

I'm also trying to avoid using multiple methods if possible and just keep the functionality within the while loop.

```
public class NthPrime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.println("Which nth prime number do you want?");
        n = IO.readInt();
        if(n <= 0) {
            IO.reportBadInput();
            return;
        }
        if(n == 1) {
            System.out.println("Nth prime number is: 2");
            return;
        }
        int primeCounter = 1;
        int currentNum = 3;
        int primeVal = 0;

        while(primeCounter < n) { 
            for(int x = 2; x < currentNum; x++) { 
                if(currentNum % x == 0) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    primeVal = currentNum;
                    primeCounter++; 
                }
            }
            currentNum++;
        }
        System.out.println(primeVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: take a long HARD look at the `if/else` you've got inside your for loop... run through it with a couple test values

Comment: Am doing so as we speak, will get back to you.  I should get a totem for this sorta thing. -.-  Thank you for your input so far.

Comment: You should acquaint yourself with the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Welcome to SO! If the answer below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that every time it encounters a number coprime to the number it's checking, it has a prime. That is to say, your if block:

```
if(currentNum % x == 0) {
    continue;
} else {
    primeVal = currentNum;
    primeCounter++; 
}
```

says "If it's composite (i.e. divisble by `x`), then there's no point in continuing to test this number. *However*, if it's not composite, then we have a prime!" This is faulty because if there's a composite number above the coprime number, your code doesn't care.

This faulty test also gets run for every single coprime number below the number you're checking.

You may be able to fix this by moving the code that updates `primeVal` and increments `primeCounter` to the place where you're *certain* that `currentNum` is prime. This would be after the for loop is done checking all the numbers below `currentNum`.

General hint: Speed up your code by looping to the square root of `currentNum`, not `currentNum` itself. It's equivalent to what you have now, but faster.

Comment: not only backwards, but totally wrong. "If remainder is non-zero, then number must be prime", on every iteration of the loop?